# Possible to run my own javascript file (myScript.user.js) in IE11?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible for me to run a script coded in JavaScript that performs a series of actions on **changing** webpages?

In Google Chrome, I'm used to putting myScript.user.js into the extensions (in the settings). What I liked about this is that it was always on/running (i.e., it was automatically executed upon a page being loaded.) This made it so that when certain conditions were met on the webpage, my script would run automatically.

Can this be done in IE11? I know I can use the dev console and input my code, or I can use bookmarklets to execute code, but is there any way I can put myScript.user.js into IE11 and have it run automatically every time a page loads, similar to how this can be done in Chrome?

Thank you!